# Is there a keyboard shortcut to show the Mini Toolbar (formatting popup) in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

When we select text in Word, a small popup toolbar (called Mini Toolbar) appears. It also shows up when you right-click on the text, along the regular context menu.

[image: Mini toolbar]

When I select text with (Ctrl-)Shift-Arrows, however, this popup is not shown. It is not even shown when I press the 'Context menu' button on the keyboard, which only shows the regular context menu in this case.

Is there a way to invoke this toolbar with the keyboard only?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

1. Open Settings -> Ease of access -> Mouse. Enable `Control your mouse with a keypad`
2. Go back to Word, select the word(s), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.
3. Release the keys, the mini toolbar should appear.

Comment: Well, technically, this does answer the question - the mini toolbar does appear, but this is when I understood that it is in no way controlled with the keyboard. I'd expect to be able to choose a formatting button with the arrow keys or some other keystroke, but it disappears as soon as you press anything.

Comment: @Giovanni I don't think this really solves the problem, I would like to get that menu when I select text with the keyboard without using any other shortcut.